# Fibonacci on 2 rows

Tags: sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9oj9.png)

Could you please help to write Fibonacci or sql for the attached

Comment: Unfortunately you have mistaken Stack Overflow for a free coding service, which it is not; this is a Q&A site where you ask questions about already researched programming problems you are unable to solve. You are expected to [make an attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and ask a specific question about what is not working with your attempt, be that an error or different output to what you require. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and edit your question to include your current attempt and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

@vinoth: Please use window function to get sum .

```
create table demo1
(
    value int
);

insert into demo1(value)
values
(2000),(100),(1),(2000),(10),(5);

with data as 

(
select value as qty,row_number() over() as  sno from demo1
)
select 
qty,
sum(qty) over(order by sno rows between unbounded preceding and current row ) as qty
from data;
```